# From one to many relationship How to get data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I built three tables and linked one to many relationship but Now I'm so confused how to get data from the main table. I've tried but it doesn't work

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN enroll,shop ON student.id = enroll.student_id, shop.student_id;");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        echo "\n\n" . $row['name'];
    }
```

Comment: you can do 2 things: either write a nested query, or just write the queries seperately for the other 2 tables using 1st primary keys

Comment: show your table structure. your dumb data, and data you want to achieve

Answer (score -1):

Here is my table structure Please help me how get we data from all table on one query.

[image]

[image]

[image]